# Cannot read property 'route' of undefined Meteor iron:router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to Meteor, i need to create post end point in my application that's why i added iron:router package in application by

> meteor add iron:router

iron:router is added successfully and visible in package list i have checked using

> meteor list

[Screenshot of package list is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKx1m.png) 
and importing it using

```
import { Router } from 'meteor/iron:router';
```

when i using this package for creating end point

```
Router.route('/testroute').post(function(){
  var response;
  if(this.request.body.userName === undefined || this.request.body.userPassword === undefined) {
      response = {
          "error" : true,
          "message" : "invalid data"
      };
  } else {
      console.log(" Request Body is : ",this.request.body);
      response = {
          "error" : false,
          "message" : "User added."
      }
  }
  this.response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  this.response.end(JSON.stringify(response)); 
  });
```

My code is not compiling now and give an error

```
Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
```

Please help me if i'm doing something wrong.
Thanks in  advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Router from 'meteor/iron:router';
```

try to import the Router without {} because Router was export default from the packages

Comment: Hey @Potato thanks for response but still facing same issue... :(

Comment: can you send the image of ur iron router version

Comment: Already added please click on Screenshot url of package list in question ..

iron:router                                1.1.2  Routing specifically designed for Meteor

Comment: is your route in the server side or client side have you try to delete the import statement

Comment: My route is server side and i also tried with deleting import statement. If i delete import statement then Router not defined errore thrown.